# QTableView not scrolling all the way to the bottom

Tags: qt

I'm mocking up a table in Qt using QTableView and QStandardItemModel. The table represents events in a log. It should scroll to the bottom so that it can show the most recent event. To be clear, I am mocking up this display, I am not adding elements to the table dynamically.

When I try using either the scrollToBottom method or the scrollTo method, the view is scrolling about 3/4 of the way down, rather than to the actual bottom of the window.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    logModel = new QStandardItemModel(THREADWATCHER_LOG_TABLE_LENGTH, 2, this);
    logTable = new QTableView;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADWATCHER_LOG_TABLE_LENGTH; i += 6) {       
        QString spawnTimeString = QString("[16:09:10:");     
        int spawnTimeMs = 186 + i * 8; // a pseudo-random choice for the interval between spawns        
        spawnTimeString.append(QString::number(spawnTimeMs) + "]");     
        logMessage[i] = new QStandardItem(spawnTimeString + " Thread \"Image Fetcher 0\" was spawned in the image processor ");
        logModel->setItem(i, 0, logMessage[i]);
        // do the same thing with [i+1], [i+2]...[i+5] 
        // so that I get six different messages in each iteration of the loop   
    }
    logTable->setModel(logModel);
    
    QModelIndex lastIndex = logMessage[THREADWATCHER_LOG_TABLE_LENGTH - 1]->index();
    logTable->scrollTo(lastIndex);
```

[image]

I get exactly the same thing if I call logTable->scrollToBottom() instead of scrolling to the last index.

Things I've tried already:

- using a single-shot timer (to ensure events have completed before scrolling)
- creating a public method that calls logTable->scrollToBottom(), and having something else call that method after this class's constructor finishes (the logic above is in the constructor)

Comment: Have you tried `QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents)` to be called before the scrolling? This should allow processing resize and show events...

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately I am still having the same problem.

Comment: try setSliderDown(true)

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan setSliderDown() doesn't change the slider position. It detects if the slider is pressed down. [Qt Documnetation: abstractslider::sliderDown](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderDown-prop)